# How to solve the integral equation?

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

I have a integral equation like following:

```
pts5 = {{2.4934, 1.2025}, {-2.1256, 
    1.0822}, {-1.3121, -0.5164}, {-2.5570, -2.5323}, {2.6419, -2.1715}};
angles = PolygonAngle[Polygon[pts5], #, "Exterior"]/Pi & /@ pts5;


(*Random Pick two random points on the X-axis*)
x1 = -1;
x2 = 0.4175;

expr1 = (s - x1)^(-angles[[1]])  (s - x2)^(-angles[[2]])  (s - 
      x3)^(-angles[[3]])  (s - x4)^(-angles[[4]]);
dist12 = EuclideanDistance[pts5[[1]], pts5[[2]]];
dist23 = EuclideanDistance[pts5[[2]], pts5[[3]]];
dist34 = EuclideanDistance[pts5[[3]], pts5[[4]]];


NSolve[{Abs[Integrate[expr1, {s, x2, x3}]]/Abs[Integrate[expr1, {s, x1, x2}]] == dist23/dist12, 
  Abs[Integrate[expr1, {s, x3, x4}]]/Abs[Integrate[expr1, {s, x1, x2}]] == dist34/dist12}, {x3, 
  x4}, Reals]
```

But I cannot solve it, I have tried `FindInstance`, or even `FindRoot`. I still fail to solve it. Maybe I need to replace `Integrate` with `NIntegrate`, but there are unknown variables in the integrand, so that doesn't work either

---

Actually I know `x3=0.6707` and `x4=1`. But I don't know hot to get it with *MMA*..

---

To further illustrate the problem, I offer a larger set of equations in follwing:

```
pts36 = {{-0.7279`, 0.5299`}, {-0.6357`, 0.4041`}, {-0.5435`, 
    0.2954`}, {-0.4514`, 0.2038`}, {-0.3595`, 0.1292`}, {-0.2679`, 
    0.07177`}, {-0.1769`, 0.0313`}, {-0.08719`, 0.007603`}, {0, 
    0}, {0.09223`, 0.008507`}, {0.1845`, 0.03403`}, {0.2767`, 
    0.07655`}, {0.3689`, 0.1361`}, {0.461`, 0.2125`}, {0.553`, 
    0.3058`}, {0.6448`, 0.4158`}, {0.7361`, 0.5419`}, {0.8265`, 
    0.6832`}, {0.9151`, 0.8374`}, {1.`, 1.`}, {0.8825`, 
    1.069`}, {0.7474`, 1.13`}, {0.6032`, 1.178`}, {0.4232`, 
    1.221`}, {0.3061`, 1.24`}, {0.1315`, 1.256`}, {0.`, 
    1.26`}, {-0.176`, 1.253`}, {-0.3484`, 1.234`}, {-0.4941`, 
    1.206`}, {-0.6206`, 1.173`}, {-0.7588`, 1.125`}, {-0.8877`, 
    1.066`}, {-1.`, 1.`}, {-0.9124`, 0.8324`}, {-0.8201`, 0.6726`}};
angles = Most[PolygonAngle[Polygon[pts36], #, "Exterior"]/Pi & /@ pts36];

vars = Table[Symbol[TemplateApply["x<*i*>"]], {i, 1, Length[angles]}];
x1 = -1;
x2 = -0.5616;
exprint = Times @@ MapThread[(s - #1)^(-#2) &, {vars, angles}];
dist[index1_, index2_] := EuclideanDistance[pts36[[index1]], pts36[[index2]]];
intfun[x1_, x2_] := With[{exprint = exprint}, NIntegrate[exprint, {s, x1, x2}]];


NSolve[Table[
  Abs[intfun[vars[[th]], vars[[th + 1]]]]/
    Abs[intfun[vars[[1]], vars[[2]]]] == 
   Abs[dist[th, th + 1]]/Abs[dist[1, 2]], {th, 2, 
   Length[angles] - 1}], vars[[3 ;;]]]
```

And I know that the solution to this equation is:

```
{-0.4274, -0.3660, -0.3320, -0.3108, -0.2964, -0.2856, -0.2771, \
-0.2690, -0.2612, -0.2532, -0.2448, -0.2360, -0.2269, -0.2180, \
-0.2100, -0.2036, -0.1994, -0.1980, -0.1972, -0.1948, -0.1902, \
-0.1809, -0.1721, -0.1525, -0.1309, -0.0866, -0.0154, 0.0807, 0.2048, \
0.3949, 0.5952, 0.6896, 1.0000}
```

Comment: V 14 gives `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`  when trying to do even the indefinite integrate `Integrate[expr1,s]`  so this is hopeless to try to do it this way.

Comment: Can you present your " the system I am dealing with consists of 32 equations"? In another case it's just empty talk.

Comment: BTW, I  see neither " differential equations"  nor "integral equations" in your current question. [Integral equations](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Integral_equation) include  unknown functions.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for your solution and I updated the question as [your comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297073/how-to-solve-the-integral-equation#comment734898_297073)

Comment: As far as I understand it, your question is related to  a Schwarz–Christoffel map.

Comment: Its numeric realization is a hard matter (see  [here](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Schwarz–Christoffel+mapping&sca_esv=213bf1ba865ab4e8&ei=Kpy4ZY_EEPbY7_UP4s2jsAk&udm=&ved=0ahUKEwiPgZDnwoSEAxV27LsIHeLmCJYQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=Schwarz–Christoffel+mapping&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiHVNjaHdhcnrigJNDaHJpc3RvZmZlbCBtYXBwaW5nMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADSOhHUABYAHABeAGQAQCYAQCgAQCqAQC4AQPIAQDiAwQYACBBiAYBkAYI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1))

Comment: There are special programs to this end and Mathematica is not a magic wand.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing your `NSolve[...]` by

```
FindMinimum[(Abs[
   NIntegrate[Evaluate[expr1], {s, x2, x3}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4]]/
  Abs[NIntegrate[Evaluate[expr1], {s, x1, x2}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4]] - 
 dist23/dist12)^2 + (Abs[
   NIntegrate[Evaluate[expr1], {s, x3, x4}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4]]/
  Abs[NIntegrate[Evaluate[expr1], {s, x1, x2}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4]] - dist34/dist12)^2, {x3, 1}, {x4, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 13]
```

> `{1.389040764948*10^-14, {x3 -> 0.6708043198243, x4 -> 1.000158525324}}`

and 11 warnings (not errors).

Comment: Do you get a lot of [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JrjR.png) while your code is running? Is there a way to stop them?

Comment: @yode: Thank you,  Decreasing `AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 5` to `AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4`, I obtain `{1.389040764948*10^-14, {x3 -> 0.6708043198243, x4 -> 1.000158525324}}` and  11 warnings (not errors). I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For small set of equations we can solve this problem using `FindRoot` (without error messages) as follows

```
pts5 = {{2.4934, 1.2025}, {-2.1256, 
    1.0822}, {-1.3121, -0.5164}, {-2.5570, -2.5323}, {2.6419, \
-2.1715}};
angles = 
  Rationalize[PolygonAngle[Polygon[pts5], #, "Exterior"]/Pi & /@ pts5,
    10^-15];


(*Random Pick two random points on the X-axis*)
x1 = -1;
x2 = 0.4175;

expr[x1_, x2_, x3_, 
   x4_] := (s - x1)^(-angles[[1]])   (s - x2)^(-angles[[2]])   (s - 
      x3)^(-angles[[3]])   (s - x4)^(-angles[[4]]);
int12[x3_?NumericQ, x4_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[expr[x1, x2, x3, x4], {s, x1, x2}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5];
int23[x3_?NumericQ, x4_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[expr[x1, x2, x3, x4], {s, x2, x3}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5];
int34[x3_?NumericQ, x4_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[expr[x1, x2, x3, x4], {s, x3, x4}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5];
dist12 = EuclideanDistance[pts5[[1]], pts5[[2]]];
dist23 = EuclideanDistance[pts5[[2]], pts5[[3]]];
dist34 = EuclideanDistance[pts5[[3]], pts5[[4]]];


eq = {Abs[int23[x3, x4]] dist12 - Abs[int12[x3, x4]] dist23, 
   Abs[int34[x3, x4]] dist12 - Abs[int12[x3, x4]] dist34};


FindRoot[eq, {{x3, 1}, {x4, 1}}]
{x3 -> 0.670787, x4 -> 1.00009}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to apply to that larger set of problems

Comment: @yode Could you show the problem to implement `FindRoot` to a large set of equations?